# shopping cart database design and the flow of putting the orders into the tables

Tags: asp.net, database

I'm creating a database in SQL Server 2005 to store orders taken.

table [customers]  : customer detail table primary key is the customer_ID which will be an identity autoincremental

table [orders] : holds 3 columns, [orderid](which is also the pk),[product_id],[quantity]

table [linking] : holds 2 columns, [customerid](as foreign key), [orderid](foreign key as well)

ordering flow :
  when customer checked out, the customer's detail will be stored to table[customers] in which a unique customer_ID will be generated.

next, using that customer_ID, the products in the shopping cart will be stored into table[orders] .

now, the problem is: how do i retrieve the auto_generated customer_ID from the table[customers]? assuming that a lot of users are checking out at the same time? After inserting the customer's detail into the table[customer], I have to use the customer_ID in the table[linking] to pair up with the orderid.

Answer (score 0):

Write a few SQL stored procedures to do this work for you. You can call this from your web application's code using ADO.NET.

1. Call proc `CreateCustomer`. It creates your CustomerID.
2. Call proc `CreateOrderForCust`.

```
CREATE PROC CreateCustomer 
  @Name varchar(100),
  @Address varchar(100)
AS
   DECLARE @CustomerID int; 

   INSERT INTO CUSTOMER([Name],[Addr]) VALUES (@Name, @Addr);

   SELECT @CustomerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

   RETURN @CustomerID;

...
CREATE PROC CreateOrderForCust
  @CustomerID int,
  @SKU int,
  @Qty int
AS
   .....
```

Comment: i got that fixed. actually i just passed in the sql into commandtext. i used @@identity instead of scope_identity().  do you think if a lot of people placing the order at the same time, the returned order identity will be the actual one that belongs to that particular buyer?

Comment: @angus myself, I always use scope_identity, rather than @@identity. You never know when a new trigger might come along in the future.